# Parse JSON in Python Issue

Tags: python, json, api, parsing, yahoo-api

I am currently working with the yahoo api.

I am able to retrieve a json response from the api call.  I am trying to parse this data in python and am currently having trouble.

Here are the process I am doing that is not parsing correctly and getting an error.

resp.content - this holds the JSON message - the json looks like below

```
{"query":{"count":1,"created":"2015-09-22T19:52:42Z","lang":"en-US","results":{"player":{"player_key":"348.p.4256","name":{"full":"Peyton Manning"}}}}}
```

Following Steps

```
 >>> import json
 >>> parsed_json = json.loads(resp.content)
```

I am wanting to only extract and print Peyton Manning

```
>>> print(parsed_json['full'])
```

When I run the print line:  I receive this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'full'
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong in this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a *nested* dictionary; dictionaries whose values are other dictionaries.

Using the [`pprint.pprint()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html#pprint.pprint) would make this clearer:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(parsed_json)
{u'query': {u'count': 1,
            u'created': u'2015-09-22T19:52:42Z',
            u'lang': u'en-US',
            u'results': {u'player': {u'name': {u'full': u'Peyton Manning'},
                                     u'player_key': u'348.p.4256'}}}}
```

You need to address the keys along a path to get the value for the `'full'` key:

```
>>> parsed_json['query']['results']['player']['name']['full']
u'Peyton Manning'
```

Comment: There is nothing special about nested dictionaries. Each time you do `dictionary[key]` the value is returned. You could do `nested = dictionary[key1]`, then use `nested[key2]`, or just directly use `dictionary[key1][key2]` for the same effect. Just keep on chaining.

Comment: I have another query that looks like so:

`{u'query': {u'count': 1,
            u'created': u'2015-09-23T12:29:56Z',
            u'lang': u'en-US',
            u'results': {u'player': {u'name': {u'full': u'Peyton Manning'},
                                     u'player_points': {u'total': u'21.24'}}}}}`

Comment: I have tried following the example above and am trying to extract the total value which is 21.24:  parsed_json['query']['count']['player_points']['total']

Comment: I get this error in response :    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: `parsed_json['query']['count']` is an integer, `1`. You want `parsed_json['query']['results']['player']['player_points']['total']`.

Comment: @bfali: you can always try out *partial* paths; try out `parsed_json['query'].keys()`, then look at each of the keys with `parsed_json['query'][key]`, then use `dict.keys()` on nested objects, etc. So `parsed_json['query']['results']['player']`  and `parsed_json['query']['results']['player'].keys()` to see what you can do with that dictionary.

Comment: thank you so much for all your help, your last comment really helped me understand better